# Symfony 3 - How to keep session id after logging in?

Tags: php, database, session, symfony

I want to use the session ID to identify the records in the database for anonymous user. When the user logs in, I would like to bind/relate the data to the user id. However, after logging in the session id is automatically changed by what I lose data binding with the user.

How can I keep the session id after logging in order to bind the user id to the data, and then change the session id?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7885

Answer (score 2):

Upon authentication, session should be migrated, unless configured otherwise. Indeed, the session ID is not retained but the data should be there.

Have you checked the `security.xml`:

```
session_fixation_strategy:  migrate
```

This above should be the default ([reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html)). What is the case with your config?

Hope this helps a bit...