# How to change phpsessid after login using symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, session, symfony-3.4

I'd like to use different session id (PHPSESSID value) before and after login to the system:

```
$this->get("session")->set("PHPSESSID", session_create_id());
```

but after doing that cannot log onto system.

I found a solution here but I don't have security.xml file: [Symfony 3 - How to keep session id after logging in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624358/symfony-3-how-to-keep-session-id-after-logging-in)

Any solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use $this->get("session")->migrate(). It should create a new session identical to the current session. https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

Comment: thank you @Thakkie could you post it down so I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: How thoughtful thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$this->get("session")->migrate();
```

It should create a new session identical to the current session.

More info here http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/http_foundation/sessions.html